# Windows 8.1 Desktop Background Solid Colour - Add Some Text

Tags: windows-8, desktop

I have a solid black windows 8.1 desktop background.
I want to add some text in the top right corner that will stay there permanently.

e.g. "MyPcName" or some other random text that I would type.

Is there any build in feature that does this or do I have to create an image?
If it needs to be an image, do I need different images for different resolutions as I connect up to an external monitor when in the office.

Comment: One free way would be to use the [Microsoft Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx) that normally would be used to do this. This is the same/similar mechanic Microsoft uses to indicate your Windows installation is limited on the desktop due to an activation issue.

Comment: BGInfo, the Microsoft tool referenced by @Ramhound, is an excellent choice for displaying system information on the background.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in feature, but using an application such as [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) will give you all those features - without having to create your custom image :)